# SQLPLUS Table Trouble

Tags: select, sqlplus

I've been using SQLPLUS lately and one of my tasks was to display a set of values from two tables (stocks, orderitems). I have done this part, but I am stuck on the last part of the question which states: "including the stocks that no order has been placed on them so far".

Here is the statement:

```
`select Stocks.StockNo, Stocks.Description, OrderItems.QtyOrd
 from Stocks INNER JOIN OrderItems
 ON Stocks.StockNo = OrderItems.StockNo;`
```

and I have gotten the correct results for this part, but the second part is eluding me, as the curernt statement doesn't display the 0 values for QtyOrd.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://oreilly.com/catalog/orsqlpluspr2/chapter/ch01.html) otherwise the `INNER JOIN` will exclude Stocks which don't have any Orders. You might also consider grouping by Stock, in order to SUM the overall quantities for each stock?

```
SELECT  Stocks.StockNo, Stocks.Description, SUM(OrderItems.QtyOrd) AS QtyOrd
FROM  Stocks 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderItems
         ON Stocks.StockNo = OrderItems.StockNo
GROUP BY Stocks.StockNo, Stocks.Description;
```

Comment: WOW, thank you Stuart. That was so helpful. I appreciate the fast response. This question can no be closed.